# How do I setup HP LaserJet M1005 Multifunction Printer on my ChromeOs Flex device

Tags: drivers, printer, hp-laserjet, google-chrome-os-flex

I have installed ChromeOs Flex on my Dell Vostro 15 3568 certified laptop. When I attach the printer via USB cable, then I got the notification that `HP Laserjet M1005 needs additional setup`.

- When I click on it, it takes me to the Printers page of the Settings app.
- On this page, I have chosen my Printer Manufacturer as "HP" and the model as "HP Laser Ns Mfp 1005".
- When I send the print request to the printer then, it said `Printed`, but there was nothing actually printed.
- I also tried for the PPD file for this printer from the link ​​https://github.com/koenkooi/foo2zjs/blob/master/PPD/HP-LaserJet_M1005_MFP.ppd but when I send print request, it said: `Filter Failed`. ​

My printer doesn't support WiFi, it only supports USB. How can I get the printer working ?

[image: See image of Printer App]

[image: See image of Printer Jobs App]

Comment: Does the printer support being connected to the mobile application HP Smart?

Comment: No, since I have using ChromeOs Flex, which does not supports android app so, I cannot use HP Smart mobile app.

Comment: You should be able to use [HP Print](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_2506940-1986942-16). My intention of using HP Smart would be to simply configure the printer to be connected to your network (I suspect it’s not)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please also tell me how to use HP Print. Because when I add it to chrome then after I connect my printer, Chromeos flex says "HP Laserjet M1005 needs additional setup". What to do now?